# I can't boot up disk options when I startup my Mac

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, startup

I recently installed Asahi Linux, and for a few months now I've had no issue with it. Now, however, my computer decided to boot me up into Asahi Linux when I started charging it after it died. Usually, when this happens and I want to go back to macOS, I just hold <kbd>Opt</kbd> and I can get back to my macOS partition, but this time it won't work. I've tried booting into safe-mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd>), Recovery Mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), resetting SMC (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pwr</kbd>), and resetting NVRAM (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), all to no avail.

It seems like possibly my keyboard is just not picking up commands until afterward, since when Asahi Linux's terminal boots up, I'm not able to type commands at all for a few seconds, or I'll be stuck on <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> or something fishy like that.

No water damage or physical damage happened in between uses, so the problem is likely software-related.

This is on an M1 Pro MacBook Pro 16-inch 2021 edition.

Any thoughts? I know this is quite a weird issue, I'm hoping I just missed something simple but I can't figure out what that might be.

Answer (score 1):

M1 Macs don't use the same key commands as Intel at boot - see
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/mac

Basically, from completely shut down, you press & hold the Power button until options appear.
Try from there...